# Using Genymotion's GPS with Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion and set up a virtual device (Google Nexus 5X 6.0.0 API 23) with Google Play Services on it so that I can access the Play Store and other Google services.

I'm now messing around with location, and it works great with Maps (change location from France to Germany to New York, ask Maps to update my location, puts me in the right place).

With the Play Store, however, it's not working. I know the Play Store displays different results based on your location, but here, whether I'm in New York, Berlin or Paris, the results are the same, whether it is the top charts or when I type a keyword. It's always the same list of apps.

I don't really know what I could try to do to fix the problem. I've tried closing down the app before changing the location, restarting the emulator... didn't help.

I've been stuck on this for a few days now, would appreciate any help / suggestions.

Comment: IIRC the Play store shows apps corresponding to the geographical area the google account is configured to belong to

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that. I will give it a try and answer my own question if it works.

Comment: They may use additional heuristics to ensure you are in the correct location so I don't know if a different account will do the trick.